# Pillow resize image not working - module has no attribute "resize"

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to import 2 images with Pillow and resize one of them to fit the other. When I use `Image.resize` I get the error

```
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'resize'
```

Here is my code: What am I doing wrong?

```
from PIL import Image

background = Image.open("/Users/user1/Downloads/2016-10-12.jpg")
foreground = Image.open("/Users/user1/Desktop/nadir.png")

bgSize = background.size
print(bgSize)

foreground = Image.resize((background.size), resample=0)

Image.alpha_composite(foreground, background)
```

Comment: try `foreground.resize`

Comment: How would you expect `resize` to know which Image you want resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `resize()` method is an instance method not a class method. The code should be

`background.resize()` instead of `Image.resize(background.size), resample=0)`

[Link to an example in the docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html#geometrical-transforms)